# grouping equal values - aggregate function problem

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, aggregate

I've created a table that lists venues in which several events take place. The same event in the same venue can have a different price. The last column calculates the total revenue for one venue.

```
SELECT     venuename,
           eventname,
           totalprice,
           SUM(totalprice) OVER (PARTITION BY venuename)
    FROM venue
    INNER JOIN event e ON venue.venueid = e.venueid
    INNER JOIN listing l ON e.eventid = l.eventid;
```

| venue | event | totalprice | sum |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Venue A | Event A | 5 | 30 |
| Venue A | Event A | 10 | 30 |
| Venue A | Event B | 5 | 30 |
| Venue A | Event A | 5 | 30 |
| Venue A | Event B | 5 | 30 |
| Venue B | Event C | 3 | 15 |
| Venue B | Event D | 6 | 15 |
| Venue B | Event D | 6 | 15 |

Now i want to group up equal events and calculate the total revenue of one event in a venue.

The result should look something like this:

| venue | event | totalprice | sum |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Venue A | Event A | 20 | 30 |
| Venue A | Event B | 10 | 30 |
| Venue B | Event C | 3 | 15 |
| Venue B | Event D | 12 | 15 |

My idea to solve this was something like this:

```
SELECT venuename,
       eventname,
       SUM(totalprice),
       SUM(totalprice) OVER (PARTITION BY venuename)
FROM venue
INNER JOIN event e ON venue.venueid = e.venueid
INNER JOIN listing l ON e.eventid = l.eventid
GROUP BY eventname;
```

But this doesn't seem to be possible since vanuename has to be part of an aggregate function as well. But i can't really come up with an idea to solve this problem.

Hope anyone of you guys can help me with this.

greetings

Comment: It is not clear why you can't add venuename to group by.

Comment: "Now i want to group up equal events and calculate the total revenue of ONE EVENT IN A VENUE" - you have solved exactly as you have stated. I don't see the problem here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can combine an agrregate and a window function

```
SELECT venuename,
       eventname,
       SUM(totalprice) totalprice,
       SUM(SUM(totalprice)) OVER (PARTITION BY venuename) sum
FROM venue
INNER JOIN event e ON venue.venueid = e.venueid
INNER JOIN listing l ON e.eventid = l.eventid
GROUP BY venuename, eventname;
```

Comment: This worked just fine. Great idea, i didn't knew about that. Thanks a lot!